# Html | Button style error

Tags: html, css

Есть файл `**main.html**` вот код кнопки. почему он не работает?

```css
  body {
  .custom-btn {
    width: 130px;
    height: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    background: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), 7px 7px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    outline: none;
  }
  .btn-9 {
    border: none;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .btn-9:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #1fd1f9;
    background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #1fd1f9 0%, #b621fe 74%);
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
  .btn-9:hover {
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), -4px -4px 6px 0 rgba(116, 125, 136, .2), inset -4px -4px 6px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), inset 4px 4px 6px 0 rgba(116, 125, 136, .3);
    color: #fff;
  }
  .btn-9:hover:after {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2) rotate(180deg);
    transform: scale(2) rotate(180deg);
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), -4px -4px 6px 0 rgba(116, 125, 136, .2), inset -4px -4px 6px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), inset 4px 4px 6px 0 rgba(116, 125, 136, .3);
  }
```

```html
<button class="custom-btn btn-9">Download</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас в стиле кнопки, зачем-то, есть `body {`, если его убрать -- всё работает:

```html
<style>
  .custom-btn {
    width: 130px;
    height: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    background: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), 7px 7px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    outline: none;
  }
  
  .btn-9 {
    border: none;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .btn-9:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #1fd1f9;
    background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #1fd1f9 0%, #b621fe 74%);
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
  
  .btn-9:hover {
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), -4px -4px 6px 0 rgba(116, 125, 136, .2), inset -4px -4px 6px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), inset 4px 4px 6px 0 rgba(116, 125, 136, .3);
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .btn-9:hover:after {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2) rotate(180deg);
    transform: scale(2) rotate(180deg);
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), -4px -4px 6px 0 rgba(116, 125, 136, .2), inset -4px -4px 6px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), inset 4px 4px 6px 0 rgba(116, 125, 136, .3);
  }
</style>
<button class="custom-btn btn-9">Download</button>
```

Comment: это немного не то что мне нужно. Я записываю всё в 1 файл

Comment: @SoftwareSec, исправил ответ. Не вижу большой разницы.